# python timer decorator - function takes effect on the original dataset which I put in the arguments

Tags: python, decorator

I'm relatively new to python decorator.

I have this decorator function.

```
def myTimer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
      t1 = time.time()
      result = func(*args, **kargs)
      t2 = time.time() - t1
      print('Execution Time (function : {}) : {} sec'.format(func.__name__, t2))
      return result

    return wrapper
```

This is just a timer function.
And, I have a method which adds a column based on another columns.

```
@myTimer
def createID(dat):
    dat['new'] = dat.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x[4:8])), axis = 1)
    return dat
```

This generates a new column whose values are just another column values combined by '_' separator.

Now, if I define the two functions above and run below,

```
tdat2 = createID(tdat)
```

And then tdat2 returns correctly but the change takes effect on tdat(original dataset), too.
I mean, tdat has 30 columns in the first place and tdat2 should have 31 columns, which is fine, but tdat also has the new column, too.

Is there any way I can fix this? 
I have tried below and it works just fine for me, but I want the argument and return values the same('dat') because of the code convention, etc.

```
@myTimer
def createID2(dat):
    result = dat.copy()
    result['new'] = result.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(map(str, x[4:8])), axis = 1)
    return result
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using pandas.  Returning a copy of a DataFrame is a reasonable approach.  If you want the same arg and return value (not sure why), just reassign the name `dat = dat.copy()`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using pandas. The inside of createID method should describe how the method converts the original 'dat' but should not actually convert it, right? But when I put the method under the umbrella of @myTimer, the command is executed on the original 'dat', too.

Comment: Just adding dat = dat.copy() to createID fixed the problem. Thanks. I'm wondering what is going underside these phenomenon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some Notes**

1. Since you don't have a class, `createID` is called a function.  It's a black box: it takes in an input, does something and returns an output.  Pythonically, functions are written in lowercase with underscores, e.g. `create_id`.
2. `my_timer()` is also a function that wraps the function it decorates, i.e. `create_id()`.  Your decorator really doesn't do anything to your wrapped function except prints something (a side effect).

So whatever happens inside the decorated function is not influenced by your decorator.  All it does is time how fast the function call runs.

---

The mutation problem you are describing is a pandas issue (see docs on [View vs Copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)).  You have resolved it with the `.copy()` method.